# Unable to find xpath using following sibling

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

This is my sample html code. I am unable to find xpath for input type="text".

Note: I need xpath refernce from the div id only.

```
<div id="PRINTDIV">
    <table id="one"></table>
    <table id="two"></table>
 </div>

 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="post value" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" >
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I am using below xpath. But not working.

/*[@id='PRINTDIV']/following-sibling::table/tr/td[2]

Please correct me.

Comment: If you provide the complete XML then many people will be able to give you a solution immediately. Without this, now everybody has to guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a slash at the beginning and need to add an extra slash before tr. In inspect element i see an additional tbody tag, though I got no idea why is it so.

```
"//div[@id='PRINTDIV']/following-sibling::table//tr/td/input[@type='text']"
```

Or try with CSS

```
"div[id='PRINTDIV'] + table tr > td > input[type='text']"
```

Why not use the id of the table to get to it directly? Is it dynamic generated id?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is not working for me - both xpath and CSS. There is no ID for the table below the div. Now edited the question.

Comment: I am using exactly the updated html in chrome and it is working for both. Are the div and table inside an iframe?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using IE 11 and it fails. Just now checked in chrome. It works for me aslo perfectly. I am using below config details for initiating IE 11. System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\SELENIUM\\SEL_PRACTICE\\driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);

Comment: @SolomonRaja what is the exception are you getting on IE??

Comment: No such element exception

Answer (score 0):

Since the div is not immediate child of root node, you can't access it through a single /. You will have to provide // to allow selenium parse and find the node in the DOM.

Hence //div should be able to access the element.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help me out with the xpath using the same in IE 11 where it is not working.